# Parsing HTML table with LXML in Python

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

I need to parse html table of the following structure:

```
<table class="table1" width="620" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 <tbody>
   <tr width="620">
     <th width="620">Smth1</th>
     ...
   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="ffffff" width="620">
     <td width="620">Smth2</td>
     ...
   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="E4E4E4" width="620">
     <td width="620">Smth3</td>
     ...
   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="ffffff" width="620">
     <td width="620">Smth4</td>
     ...
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Python code:

```
r = requests.post(url,data)
html = lxml.html.document_fromstring(r.text)
rows = html.xpath(xpath1)[0].findall("tr")
#Getting Xpath with FireBug
data = list()
for row in rows:
    data.append([c.text for c in row.getchildren()])
```

But I get this on the third line:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The task is to form python dict from this. Number of rows could be different.

**UPD.**
Changed the way I'm getting html code to avoid possible problems with requests lib. Now it's a simple url:

```
html = lxml.html.parse(test_url)
```

This proves everyting is Ok with html:

```
lxml.html.open_in_browser(html)
```

But still the same problem:

```
rows = html.xpath(xpath1)[0].findall('tr')
data = list()
for row in rows:
    data.append([c.text for c in row.getchildren()])
```

Here is the xpath1:

```
'/html/body/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/center/table'
```

**UPD2.** It was found experimentally, that xpath crashes on:

```
xpath1 = '/html/body/table/tbody'
print html.xpath(xpath1)
#print returns []
```

If xpath1 is shorter, then it seeem to work well and returns `[<Element table at 0x2cbadb0>]` for `xpath1 = '/html/body/table'`

Comment: Pro tip: please include the *full* traceback of python errors to reduce the need guess for anyone helping you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't include the XPath, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if I understood correctly, this should work

```
xpath1 = "tbody/tr"
r = requests.post(url,data)
html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
rows = html.xpath(xpath1)
data = list()
for row in rows:
    data.append([c.text for c in row.getchildren()])
```

This is making a list of one item lists though, like this:

```
[['Smth1'], ['Smth2'], ['Smth3'], ['Smth4']]
```

To have a simple list of the values, you can use this code

```
xpath1 = "tbody/tr/*/text()"
r = requests.post(url,data)
html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
data = html.xpath(xpath1)
```

This is all assuming that r.text is exactly what you posted up there.

Comment: Described all changes in UPD, but the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

Your `.xpath(xpath1)` XPath expression failed to find any elements. Check that expression for errors.

Comment: Included XPath1 into description, checked it one more time with FireBug

Comment: run `print html.xpath(xpath1)` to test, not in FireBug.

Comment: Described the situation in UPD2